# Can anyone understand my hosting heroku problem

Tags: rest, express, heroku, knex.js

can anyone understand why my heroku app keeps returning an "Internal Server Error". when I run it locally it all seems to work fine. im using Knex, express and postgresql and when I run heroku logs --tail, I get these errors (which to me looks like the routes are broken, except locally is fine),.

the GitHub repo is: https://github.com/jamesgill11/quiz-server.git

these are my error. if any other code is needed I'm happy to post up.

```
2021-02-23T12:55:19.845454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com request_id=10a882db-8dc5-4386-8522-f8b670239dfd fwd="188.223.116.76" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=281 protocol=https
2021-02-23T12:55:20.383722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com request_id=50be0650-dd26-476a-bb67-9e042d36bb2e fwd="188.223.116.76" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=281 protocol=https
2021-02-23T12:55:23.452736+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com request_id=f0d4d743-42a3-4d62-8b19-063de3f19524 fwd="188.223.116.76" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=281 protocol=https
2021-02-23T12:55:26.686396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/questions" host=my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com request_id=76aa1e8c-85d1-4e63-864b-9e3eca2431de fwd="188.223.116.76" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=500 bytes=289 protocol=https
2021-02-23T12:55:26.810018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-quiz-server.herokuapp.com request_id=67fb709a-451e-4bcc-a758-0ed01e5de4da fwd="188.223.116.76" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=281 protocol=https
```

also I don't have any routes /favicon.ico or any favicons? so im not sure they this is there.

thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: just a bit more insight on the issue. the code seems to run absolutely fine when the environment is set to development but when I change it to production, it doesn't seem to work??

Comment: so I ran a few console.logs and I am getting this error -

Error: Unable to acquire a connection
at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/Users/jamesgill/Desktop/todoList/Quiz/Quiz-server/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:339:13)
at Runner.ensureConnection (/Users/jamesgill/Desktop/todoList/Quiz/Quiz-server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:264:8)

it looks like its not connecting to the PG database on heroku. I have tried changing the connectionString in the knexfile.js to the actually Postgres_url string but its still having none of it and will not connect.

Comment: I also tried setting the SSL to true and creating an heroku add-on but still not luck 